# FB.ui Send Dialog 500 error... but only on link to my site?

Tags: facebook, facebook-javascript-sdk

I'm using FB.ui to show the Send dialog. It works perfectly... unless I specify the link to the new site I'm working on.

**This works** (FB dialog displays, recipient receives message):

```
FB.ui({       
    method: 'send',
    name: 'Check out my new site!',
    link: 'http://nytimes.com/',
});
```

**But it breaks when I change the link value to 'http://plumspotter.com/'.**

When I change 'http://nytimes.com/' to the site I'm working on 'http://plumspotter.com/', it appears to work, but the recipient does not receive the message.

Using Firebug > Net panel I see that when FB.ui posts to facebook.com/dialog/send it's returns a 500 (internal server error).

Any idea why Facebook wouldn't allow me to use FB.ui to send a link to http://plumspotter.com/?

Answer (score 6):

I recently faced the same problem. Facebook will analyse your page before sending a link, if it cant, it will throw a 500 error.

**More info:**

If your page does not return a 200 code, it will not analyse your page, and will throw up a 500 error.

Make sure the page you link does not redirect to any other pages, even if they are within your app. A redirect is 3xx code - which is not accepted by facebook.

Since your site has htaccess - facebook cant scroll through the page you linked - and hence will throw up an error.

Answer (score 2):

By visiting your site http://plumspotter.com I get a htaccess password prompt: `Access to the Plumspotter Alpha is restricted`. If you remove the barrier, it should work without trouble.

Comment: Thank you! That makes sense. The site is still in QA now so we have it locked down. We'll come up with an alternate way to test before going live.

Answer (score 0):

After several hours of problems I realized that this type of sharing does not support link redirects type `header ()`. The simple solution is a redirection in the metas: `<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="0;URL=">` and above, **request a debug** the old url that you use https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug . And... It's work.

Answer (score 0):

I received the same error (HTTP 500) and it turned out to be that I was linking to an **IP address**:

**Bad**: `http://173.194.75.106`

**Good**: `http://google.com`